# 'Error 403 Forbidden' error on Geoserver during WFS Preview while WMS Previews are OK

Tags: geoserver

The version of the Geoserver I'm using is 2.19.2. Actually I had no issue with any kind of previews since the installation and I can still call the WFS layers to use them in QGIS or any other map client. But now somehow when I clicked on any of the WFS types (gml,geojson) on the preview screen, I only receive the message below.

```
HTTP ERROR 403 Forbidden
URI:    /data/gaist/ows
STATUS: 403
MESSAGE:    Forbidden
SERVLET:    dispatcher
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

"Service access rules list" is the key for the solution of this issue.
If you've created new roles, users and granted access rules on separate paths like wfs.GetCapabilities for them, then even if wfs.* path is granted for admin role, you need to re-grant admin access on these new paths. Otherwise it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean with that? can you clarify ?